# How can I check if two numbers are equal (with some allowed error)?

Tags: time-series, mean, stationarity, average-precision

I have a lot (about 10000 or more) measurement results. I measured the performance of different algorithms (it doesnt really matter which algorithms for now on). I want to check if my measurement results are stationary or not. I can simply check it with SIMPLE MOVING AVERAGE, and I did it. The thing is, I have to compare my moving averages I calculated, check if they're equal or not. If they're equal, my data set is stationary. But having so much data I need to consider a small error, with I can assume my means are equal.

Example:

1. I have a data set with the measurement results: `X = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};`, so `N = 10`
2. I chose the window, `w = 3`
3. I calculated means with the simple moving average method, stored means in `SAM` table:

   (1+2+3)/3 = 2, (2+3+4)/3 = 3, (3+4+5)/3 = 4, ..., (8+9+10)/3 = 9

so `SAM = {2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0}`

1. For my data to be stationary, `SAM` table should look like this: `SAM = {9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0}` (moving means are equal)
2. Having `X` set with some randomness, my SAM will not look quite that neat, it could be `SAM = {9.2, 9.7, 9.3, 9.6, 9.4, 10.0, 9.1, 9.7}`

   and heres my question: how can I calculate the acceptable error with I can assume my means are equal?

When `SAM` looks like this: `SAM = {9.2, 9.7, 9.3, 9.6, 9.4, 10.0, 9.1, 9.7}` and the error is, lets say +/-0.7 then I can consider my means as equal and my data stationary. The main problem is, *how can I calculate this acceptable error?*

Comment: Constant mean does not imply stationarity.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confusing two things:

- You would like to know if your moving averages are equal to each other or to the "true measurent"

You could do a classic hypothesis test that the true mean of all the moving averages you assembled is equal to your null hypothesis mean,

And use the standard deviations you find on your moving averages to calculate confidence intervals.

- You would like to know if your moving averages are constant in time, fluctuating around the true mean and hence stationary

Now you need to use the time dimension and you will have to deal with the classic stationary tests (a.k.a. unit root tests). Given this case, I would test for non-stationary with deterministic or stochastic trend (depending on the time period) to find out if the measurements for example increase over time.

I also think it is not necessary to use the moving averages, you loose information by doing so, I would apply them on the raw data.

Comment: But my teacher said that I can check for the stationarity with moving average and moving variance methods. And if my moving means AND moving variances are equal, I then can consider my data stationary. Isnt that right?

Comment: What do you see when you plot the moving averages over time?

Comment: Heres what I see (plotted it with GNUplot): http://s28.postimg.org/i4op6i91p/image.png. My example data (moving means calculated for different `X` set. In the first column I have my running mean and in the second one, number of test - first test, second test, etc.): http://pastie.org/private/p9hynk3ecftpycjmxwnhma. So what can you say now?

Comment: Based on these values, you can probably find a significant trend, but the confidence intervals of the trend will be very small. Therefore, can you not use less neighbouring values in your moving average calculation, so you have more data points? The more data points, the smaller the confidence intervals.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to generate more data but that's not the point here. My question is, if I can say (by looking on a plotted figure) is my data stationary or not? For the picture I posted I would say that they're not stationary but take a look this picture: http://s13.postimg.org/xfve8dv3r/test.png. Here mean as well as the variance are ALMOST constant. In this case, can I say that my data is stationary?

Comment: Again, it is a very complex procedure to test if data are stationary. Basically, you would have to test for a unit root. Let's keep it simple, and say we are going to test if there is a linear trend in your moving averages over time (massive assumption, maybe it is quadratic or seasonal). These are the results out of R based on the 8 data points you posted before: http://postimg.org/image/ddpa7vzpr/ . So there is a linear trend in these data points and you would conclude not stationary. Again, this too straightforward, and test for stationary includes a lot more!